# proyecto maven .war no corre en ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, maven

tengo un proyecto maven .war que corre muy bien en tomcat 7,8 y 9 tanto en windows como en mac, pero me ha resultado imposible correr el proyecto en ubuntu server.

Si me descomprime el proyecto y me genera la carpeta en el webapps, al principio creí que era por el contexto, y cree un .xml en catalina/localhost. En el manager de tomcat me muestra que la aplicación esta corriendo, pero cuando intento entrar a la aplicación me marca el error http 404. La verdad no tengo idea de porque no me corre en ubuntu server y en otros sistemas si. Les estaría muy agradecido si me podrían ayudar. 
de antemano gracias por su atención

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya pude resolver el problema, se trataba del JDK,  ubuntu server tenia por defecto el openjdk y mi aplicación ocupa el oracle jdk, por ese motivo no funcionaba, solo lo cambie y funciono.

Saludos